# Is there anyway to trap the event of MDI Child loading for the first time?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm trying to force an always maximize setting.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

1. Set your child form's WindowState property to Maximized.
2. Set your child form's FormBorderStyle property to FixedDialog.
3. In your child's Resize event set the ControlBox property to False.